# Output multiple audio to individual sound card channels

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I have an eight channel sound card. 8 audio in and 8 audio out. When the driver for the sound card is installed, the following is shown on Playback devices.

- Play 1-2
- Play 3-4
- Play 5-6
- Play 7-8

I can enumerate all 4 devices (Play 1-2,Play 3-4) and play on each of them. The current situation only allows me to have 4 audio outputs. The sound card also has individual audio out wires/port for each channel.

What I want to do is to play on Play 1, Play 2, Play 3, etc. Is there any way to achieve this. I am currently using NAudio to enumerate and playback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play two independent mono streams out of one of the stereo pairs using `MultiplexingSampleProvider` or `MultiplexingWaveProvider`. If you want to treat the whole soundcard as a single device, then I've found `AsioOut` tends to be the only option and again you can use the multiplexing providers to route individual NAudio wavestreams to the different device outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to do it by using asio output channel offsets that was included in the demo. Thanks for the awesome library!

Comment: Quick question: i'm now trying to use asio recording and playing with multi-threading. (Start a new thread for every 1 channel playback/record) However, I'm getting STAThread error so I changed my code to use new objects of AsioOut for every 1 channel. But I get this "error code [ASE_InvalidMode] while calling ASIO method <createBuffers>" on initRecordAndPlayback method